# What would install VMWare Horizon Client?

Tags: vmware

I have a new icon on my Windows desktop, VMWare Horizon Client.

Here is its About box:

[image]

I didn't even know what it was until I googled it.

My question is: how did it get there? I did not explicitly install it. What software or process would install it? The only thing I installed recently is an update to iTunes.

### UPDATE

I tried the event viewer suggestion, using these settings:

[image]

...but got no results:

[image]

Comment: Did you install anything to work with a remote terminal or work server?

Comment: You might also check that log file, or check Add-Remove programs to see what else would have been installed around 9:52 on 2017-10-20

Comment: What VMWare products do you have installed.  Edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: @ernie: No, not on purpose, anyway

Comment: @Ramhound: None that I am aware of.

Comment: Is this on a personal computer or on a work computer that is potentially managed by your employer?

Comment: @jmaesdlin: personal laptop

Answer (score 2):

You can find out when and who installed the software by filtering the eventlog.

1. Open the application log
2. Filter
3. Event sources: MsiInstaller
4. Event IDs to look for

11728,11707,1033

Comment: Please see my update